# Trigger a event when the moving marker reaches a certain latlng

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am Using [this](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker) plugin for moving a marker around a polyline.

Here is how the moving marker is initiated.

```
var locations = [
  ["LOCATION_1",25.700769, 82.300140],
  ["LOCATION_2",26.600969, 83.400260],
  ["LOCATION_3",27.600969, 84.400260],
  ["LOCATION_4",28.600969, 85.400260],
  ["LOCATION_5",29.600969, 86.400260],
  ["LOCATION_6",24.600969, 87.400260],
  ["LOCATION_7",23.500969, 88.200260],
  ["LOCATION_8",22.400969, 89.300260],
  ["LOCATION_9",25.700569, 90.400000]
];

var latlng = array();

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  latlngs.push([locations[i][1],locations[i][2]]);
}

var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker(latlngs,
  [2500,4000,2000,5000,4000,5000,3000,2000,4000], {
  autostart: true
});
```

I want to popup a message every time the marker reaches the coordinates in  `locations` array.
Is there any way to trigger a event whenever the marker reaches a certain `latlng` coordiantes ?

Or is there any other way to bind a popup when the marker reacches a certain point.

Comment: You'll need to trigger the event handler every time you change `latlng` and put logic that checks what is the `latlng` before executing what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First register an event that catches `start` state

```
myMovingMarker.on('start',function(event) {
  // console log your event
  console.log(event)
});
```

I am not entirely sure but there should be a property called `latlng` inside your `event.target`

once you have your `latlng`

```
myMovingMarker.on('move',function(event) {
  // ... you already have your lat and lng here
  // check if your latlng is in your array here
  if (condition) {
     myMovingMarker
       .bindPopup('<b>My popup content !</b>', {closeOnClick: false})
       .openPopup()
  } else {
     myMovingMarker.closePopup()
     myMovingMarker.unbindPopup()
  }
});
```